# JSON Parsing in Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, django, json, tastypie

I have an API that returns this in JSON:

```
{"meta": {"limit": 20, "next": null, "offset": 0, "previous": null, "total_count": 1}, "objects": [{"cost": 1000, "amount": "$10 Gift Card", "id": 2, "resource_uri": "/api/amount/2/", "slug": "10-gift-card"}]}
```

When I'm trying to parse it in jQuery, I can access the meta values just fine, but I'm having trouble accessing the values in objects. To be specific, I need to have access to "cost" and "amount" when I make a call to this api. Any help?

Comment: Did you try: `yourObject.objects[0].cost`

Comment: @PSL Thanks, was easy enough, lol. At the risk of asking for too much, what way would you recommend making the ajax call? I'm thinking of just using  $.ajax()

Answer (score 0):

**Working demo** http://jsfiddle.net/QS2FB/

- http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.parseJSON/

Hope rest fits your needs `:)`

**Code**

```
var data = '{"meta": {"limit": 20, "next": null, "offset": 0, "previous": null, "total_count": 1}, "objects": [{"cost": 1000, "amount": "$10 Gift Card", "id": 2, "resource_uri": "/api/amount/2/", "slug": "10-gift-card"}]}';

var parsed = JSON.parse(data);

$(parsed).each(function (i) {
    alert(parsed.objects[i].cost);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

assuming you are using `$.ajax` the response will be parsed for you!

```
$.ajax({
  url: '/yourservice.json',
  success: function(data){
      console.log(data.meta.limit) //logs '20'
  },
});
```

http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/